# Load All posts with their tags into an array Laravel eloquent polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I need to fetch all posts existed in my table with all their tags into an array. As you see below, this query just gets the posts that have tags but I need all posts even they don't have any tags. In addition, I need to have a `tag:[]` variable in my array but I don't know how to get all posts with their tags in one query.

Thank you in advance.

```
public function getItemsWithTags(array $attr)
{
        return self::$model::
        whereNotNull('title')->
        whereNotNull('content')->
        whereNotNull('author')->
        whereNotNull('category')->
        whereNotNull('img_url')->
        has('tags')->
        get()->
        toArray();
}

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    protected $table;
    protected $primaryKey;


    use SoftDeletes;

}

class BlogModel extends BaseModel
{

    protected $table = 'blog';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';


    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(TagsModel::class,'taggable',null,null,'tag_id');
    }
}


class TagsModel extends BaseModel
{

    protected $table = 'tags';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function blog()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(BlogModel::class,"taggable");
    }


}
```

the Output of this query:

```
{
            "id": 28,
            "title": "dfg",
            "content": "<ul>\n<li>rdgrdgf</li>\n<li>dfg</li>\n<li>dg</li>\n<li>dgf</li>\n<li>dfg</li>\n</ul>",
            "author": "gd",
            "category": "Design",
            "img_url": "uploads/post/Screenshot from 2020-03-27 20-34-42_7dc41dca1ebc4dabcb921fc7f4c4744a.png",
            "created_at": "2020-05-03T18:47:38.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-05-03T18:47:38.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "category_id": 7
        }
```

and what I need is :

```
{
            "id": 28,
            "title": "dfg",
            "content": "<ul>\n<li>rdgrdgf</li>\n<li>dfg</li>\n<li>dg</li>\n<li>dgf</li>\n<li>dfg</li>\n</ul>",
            "author": "gd",
            "category": "Design",
            "img_url": "uploads/post/Screenshot from 2020-03-27 20-34-42_7dc41dca1ebc4dabcb921fc7f4c4744a.png",
            "created_at": "2020-05-03T18:47:38.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-05-03T18:47:38.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "user_id": 1,
            "category_id": 7,
            "tags":['tag1','tag2']
        }
```

Comment: You can use the `with` method for this, change `has('tags')` to with `with('tags')`

Comment: Dear @Merijndk, thanks for your comment but it retrieved a empty array of taggs

Comment: Do you have the tags method on the model you're querying?

Comment: yes I edit my question and add my models you can see it

Answer (score 1):

```
return self::$model::
    with('tags')->
    whereNotNull('title')->
    whereNotNull('content')->
    whereNotNull('author')->
    whereNotNull('category')->
    whereNotNull('img_url')->
    get()->
    toArray();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You use `has` as the name tells, this method checks if there is a tag relationship, use with instead:

```
public function getItemsWithTags(array $attr)
{
        return self::$model::
        whereNotNull('title')->
        whereNotNull('content')->
        whereNotNull('author')->
        whereNotNull('category')->
        whereNotNull('img_url')->
        with('tags')->
        get()->
        toArray();
}
```